# Error "extra argument in call" when passing argument to method

Tags: swift

I am trying to write the following Objective-C code in swift:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfTheWeek;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit 
       startDate:&startOfTheWeek 
        interval:&interval 
         forDate:now];
```

it will write the beginning of this week to `startOfTheWeek` and the weeks duration to `interval`.

In the playground I write

```
let now:NSDate = NSDate()
var startDate:NSDate
var duration: NSTimeInterval // also tried "var duration: CMutablePointer<NSTimeInterval>"
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
cal.rangeOfUnit(unit: NSCalendarUnit.WeekCalendarUnit, startDate: startDate, interval: duration, forDate: now)"
```

Although code completion tells me the signature is

```
cal.rangeOfUnit(<#unit: NSCalendarUnit#>, startDate: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSDate?>, interval: <#CMutablePointer<NSTimeInterval>#>, forDate: <#NSDate?#>)
```

an error occurs saying `Extra argument 'interval' in call`

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried

```
cal.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.WeekCalendarUnit, startDate: startDate, interval: duration, forDate: now)
```

but this yields the error

> "could not find an overload for 'rangeOfUnit' that accepts the supplied arguments."

Comment: Try `cal.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.WeekCalendarUnit, startDate: &startDate, interval: &duration, forDate: now)`, I do not have the compiler here so I cannot check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
let now = NSDate()
var startDate: NSDate? = nil
var duration: NSTimeInterval = 0
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

cal.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.WeekCalendarUnit, startDate: &startDate,
    interval: &duration, forDate: now)
```

(By default, the first parameter has no external name and thus should not be named.)

Comment: "could not find an overload for 'rangeOfUnit' that accepts the supplied arguments."